# Swift: Extending Array, Value of type _ has no member _

Tags: arrays, swift, extend

I'm trying to extend Array to return a sub array.
the line let b = arr.objectsAtIndexes([1,3,5]) produces the error "Value of type '[Int]' has no member 'objectsAtIndexes' [image: playground screenshot]

```
import Foundation

var arr = [Int](6..<19)
let b = arr.objectsAtIndexes([1,3,5])
b = b.append(1)

extension Array {
    func objectsAtIndexes(indexes: [Int]) -> [Element] {
        var returnArray = [Element]()
        for i in indexes {
            returnArray.append(self[i])
        }
        return returnArray
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use that extension below the extension declaration this way:

```
import Foundation

extension Array {
    func objectsAtIndexes(indexes: [Int]) -> [Element] {
        var returnArray = [Element]()
        for i in indexes {
            returnArray.append(self[i])
        }
        return returnArray
    }
}

var arr = [Int](6..<19)
var b = arr.objectsAtIndexes([1,3,5])
b = b.append(1)
```

And replace this line:

```
b = b.append(1)
```

With this line:

```
b.append(1)
```

And your result will be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After defining the `extension`, you should call your method. Check this [Extension reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html)

also `.append` don't return any value, so don't assign it

```
extension Array {
   func objectsAtIndexes(indexes: [Int]) -> [Element] {
       var returnArray = [Element]()
       for i in indexes {
           returnArray.append(self[i])
       }
       return returnArray
   }
}

var arr = [Int](6..<19)
var b = arr.objectsAtIndexes([1,3,5])
// Do not assign to b
b.append(1)
```